# Conditional Formik Form Validation Using Yup

Tags: javascript, formik, yup

I have a form field (shapes) that should be required when at least one of two other fields (colors & sizes) next to it are filled out. I've tried using a logical OR (||) operator, but it doesn't seem to be working. At the moment, the shapes field is only dependent on the colors field; however, if I were to switch the places of the `'colors'` and `'sizes'` in the OR condition, the shapes field is then only dependent on the sizes field.

This is how my code currently looks:

```
const formSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  colors: Yup.string().when('sizes', {
    is: (value) => Boolean(value),
    then: Yup.string().required,
    otherwise: Yup.string().nullable(),
  }),
  sizes: Yup.string().when('colors', {
    is: (value) => Boolean(value),
    then: Yup.string().required,
    otherwise: Yup.string().nullable(),
  }),
  shapes: Yup.string().when('colors' || 'sizes', {
    is: (value) => Boolean(value),
    then: Yup.string().required,
    otherwise: Yup.string().nullable(),
  }),
}, ['colors', 'sizes']);
```

I have a hunch that the way how I structured the OR condition for shapes is the issue. I'd appreciate it if someone could help me understand why my code above isn't working the way I'm desiring.

Comment: `'colors' || 'sizes'` is the same thing as `'colors'`. Please see the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR#description). I’m not familiar with Yup, so I don’t know what the correct syntax is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code achieves what I was attempting earlier:

```
const formSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  colors: Yup.string().when('sizes', {
    is: (value) => Boolean(value),
    then: Yup.string().required,
    otherwise: Yup.string().nullable(),
  }),
  sizes: Yup.string().when('colors', {
    is: (value) => Boolean(value),
    then: Yup.string().required,
    otherwise: Yup.string().nullable(),
  }),
  shapes: Yup.string().when(['colors', 'sizes'], {
    is: (colors, sizes) => Boolean(colors) || Boolean(sizes),
    then: Yup.string().required,
    otherwise: Yup.string().nullable(),
  }),
}, ['colors', 'sizes']);
```